# Consultar campo y si es 1 enviar mensaje o redirigirlo a la cabecera

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito que al iniciar sesión se verifique si el campo 'oportunidad' esta en 1, salga un mensaje que diga "Usted ya no tiene más oportunidad" y si el campo esta en 0 que le permita ingresar. Ya las verificaciones de usuario y contraseña ya las hace el código, pero ignora la consulta sql en la que especifico que se consulte ese campo. Mil gracias aquí el código.

```
//se lee la cookie de sesion
session_start();
//se establece una conexión a la base de datos
include 'conexion.php';
//se validarán los campos si la sesion aún no está abierta


   if (empty($_SESSION) and isset($_POST['datos_introducidos_usuario'])){
    //se escaparán caracteres peligrosos
       $nombre_de_usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['datos_introducidos_usuario']);
       $contraseña_introducida=$_POST['datos_introducidos_contraseña'];
       //se hará la consulta a la base de datos
       $consulta='select * from nombre_tabla where columna_usuario="'.$nombre_de_usuario.'"';
   //si hubo un resultado
   if ($ejecución_de_la_consulta=$conexion->query($consulta)){
       //se obtiene la contraseña registrada
       $contraseña_guardada=$ejecución_de_la_consulta->fetch_assoc();
       //se compara la contraseña
       $verificar_contraseña=password_verify($contraseña_introducida,$contraseña_guardada['columna_password']);  

       $sql= 'SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = $nombre_de_usuario AND oportunidad = 0';
       mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);    
       //si el resultado de la comparación ha sido verdadero
       if ($verificar_contraseña AND $sql){
           //se asigna la sesión y redirecciona
           $_SESSION['name']=$nombre_de_usuario;
           header ('location: home.php');
       }//si la contraseña es incorrecta
       else{
           header ('location: ./');
       }
   }//si el usuario no está registrado

   else{
       header ('location: ./');
   }
}//si hay una sesion abierta o no se enviaron datos
else{
   header ('location: ./');
}
?>
```

Comment: Veo en tu segundo `SQL` un pequeño error que no has puesto las comillas simples, prueba lo siguiente: `$sql= "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$nombre_de_usuario' AND oportunidad = 0 ";` Luego tambien tienes un pequeño fallo aqui: `if ($verificar_contraseña AND $sql){` cambia `AND` por `&&`

Comment: Luego realmente para comprobar dicha consulta correctamente, para ver si es verdadero o falso, haria lo siguiente: `$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$nombre_de_usuario' AND oportunidad = 0 ")` y luego quedaria asi `if ($verificar_contraseña && $resultado){`

Comment: Muhas gracias. Lo he corregido de la forma que me indicas, ahora el error esta en las ultimas lineas: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\archivo_destino.php on line 40

Comment: Así a simple vista no veo el error, suele ser algún pequeño fallo de sintaxis. Aun así te aconsejo a usar sentencia preparadas, son mucho más seguras. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenías un pequeño fallo en tu consulta, se te olvido las comillas simples `'`, quedaría así: `columna_usuario = '$nombre_de_usuario'`

No usaria en este comprobación *AND* `if ($verificar_contraseña AND $sql){`sino `&&`

Luego, te he optimizado un poco el código, también he cambiado un poco la estructura, usaría la función `num_rows` para comprobar si existe registro o no en la Base de Datos, es decir, obtiene el número de filas de un resultado.

> **nota:** El comportamiento de mysqli_num_rows() depende de si es que se utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer mysqli_num_rows() no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta que todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas.

También sería posible optar por añadir `COUNT(*)` en tu consulta `SQL`.

Luego a tus consultas he añadido `LIMIT 1` para obtener un único registro, ya que me imagino que tus usuarios son únicos (unique) en tu Base de Datos.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php 
//se inicia la sesión
session_start();
//se establece una conexión a la base de datos
include 'conexion.php';
//se validarán los campos si la sesion aún no está abierta

if ( !isset($_SESSION) && isset($_POST['datos_introducidos_usuario']) ) {
    //se escaparán caracteres peligrosos
    $nombre_de_usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['datos_introducidos_usuario']);
    $contraseña_introducida = $_POST['datos_introducidos_contraseña'] ?: '';

    //se hará la consulta a la base de datos
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$nombre_de_usuario' LIMIT 1";    
    $query_passw = $conexion->query($consulta);

   //si hubo un resultado
   if ( $query_passw->num_rows > 0 ) {
        //se obtiene datos BD
        if ($data = $query_passw->fetch_assoc() )          
           
           //Consulta 'oprtunidad'
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$nombre_de_usuario' AND oportunidad = 0 LIMIT 1";        
           $query_oportunindad = $conexion->query($sql);    
           
           //si la contraseña es correcto y existe registro en BD 'oprtunidad es = 0'
           if (password_verify($contraseña_introducida,$data['columna_password']) && $query_oportunindad->num_rows > 0) {
               //se asigna la sesión y redirecciona
               $_SESSION['name'] = $nombre_de_usuario;
               header('location: home.php');
           // No existe resultado 'oportunidad'
           } elseif ($query_oportunindad->num_rows == 0 && password_verify($contraseña_introducida,$data['columna_password'])) {
               echo "La variable opurtunidad esta en 1";
           //si la contraseña es incorrecta
           } else{             
               header('location: ./');
           }

           $query_oportunindad->close();
        }

    } else{
        //si el usuario no está registrado
        header('location: ./');
    }
    $query_passw->close();
//si hay una sesion abierta o no se enviaron datos
} else{
   header('location: ./');
}
?>
```

Te aconsejo a usar **[sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** para mejor la seguridad en tu desarrollo y [evitar la inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio tu ayuda.